# wget and grep generate - too many arguments

Tags: bash, grep, wget

I have the following code which runs wget with a list of words in filename and then trying to grep a text but keep on struggling where the right back ticks should be cause i'm getting "too many arguments"
also, do you think it is better to use Curl ?

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

filename=$1

ip=http://172.29.46.28/

while read -r line

 do

name="$line"

if [ `wget -q -O - "$ip""$name" | grep "text"` ]
then
   echo "found"
 fi
done < "$filename"
```

Comment: Quote your variable assignments: `ip="http://172.29.46.28/"` because that IP is a string literal and should be treated as such.

Answer (score 0):

I would change the if statement, to not include the output of the command (that could potentially be too long).

Just do:

```
wget -q -O - "${ip}${name}" | grep -qs "text"

if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
  echo "found"
fi
```

Comment: Also note that using grep -qs (to make it silent) is faster, as it will end as soon as one line is matched. Otherwise it has to process all its stdin.